# MySQL, Select value based on conditional count of grouped items

Tags: mysql

I have a table `buildings` which looks like:

```
+----+------------------+-------+
| id | accommodation_id | type  |
+----+------------------+-------+
| 1  | 2                | Villa |
+----+------------------+-------+
| 2  | 2                | Suite |
+----+------------------+-------+
| 3  | 5                | Villa |
+----+------------------+-------+
```

I what for each accommodation to determine which type it is by this logic:
If the accommodation has **more** than 1 building use the hard code value of `Accommodation` otherwise `buildings.type` column.

The expected output should looks like

```
+---------------+
| type          |
+---------------+
| Accommodation | <- the result for accommodation_id=2
+---------------+
| Villa         | <- the result for accommodation_id=5
+---------------+
```

I've tried this query

```sql
SELECT IF(Count(id) = 1, type, 'accommodation') AS type 
FROM   `buildings` 
WHERE accommodation_id = 2
GROUP  BY accommodation_id
```

It fails because of usage of `type` which is not in the group (fault of **only_full_group_by**).

If I add `type` to the grouping it returns not required result

```
+---------------+
| type          |
+---------------+
| Accommodation | <- the result for accommodation_id=2 & id=1
+---------------+
| Accommodation | <- the result for accommodation_id=2 & id=2
+---------------+
| Villa         | <- the result for accommodation_id=5 & id=3
+---------------+
```

I'm using MySQL8 with sql_mode=**only_full_group_by**

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes, that was how I interpreted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to count the distinct values of `type` for each `accommodation_id`, and if greater than 1, output `Accommodation`, otherwise the `type`:

```
SELECT accommodation_id,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT type) > 1 THEN 'Accommodation'
            ELSE MIN(type)
       END AS type
FROM buildings
GROUP BY accommodation_id
```

Output:

```
accommodation_id    type
2                   Accommodation
5                   Villa
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/64kFYCRibACxQZYisNgxV5/0)

Comment: @felixmosh basically `COUNT(DISTINCT type)` counts all the distinct values of `type` for each value of `accommodation_id`. In this case, the values are 2 for `id =2` and  1 for `id = 5`. The `CASE` expression compares that value to 1, and if greater, returns `Accommodation`, otherwise it returns `MIN(type)`. We have to use `MIN(type)` because of `only_full_group_by` mode, however since in this situation there is only one value of `type`, `MIN(type) === type`

Comment: Ha, cool, so `Min` forces to return only one value, which satisfies `only_full_group_by`

Comment: @felixmosh exactly!

Comment: It can be done with my query with usage of Min as well,
`SELECT If(Count(buildings.id)=1 ,Min(buildings.type), 'Accommodation') as type FROM buildings where buildings.accommodation_id=172 group by buildings.accommodation_id`

Comment: @felixmosh yes, that should work too. I prefer to use `CASE` to `IF` as it is supported by more versions of SQL, but for just MySQL `IF` works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Just a slight improvement on Nick's answer +1, to make the query sargable:

```
SELECT
    id,
    CASE WHEN MIN(type) <> MAX(type) THEN 'Accommodation' ELSE MIN(type) END AS type
FROM buildings
GROUP BY id;
```

The above query should be able to use the following index:

```
(id, type)
```

The reason for this is that it only uses `MIN` and `MAX`, so for each `id` group the min and max type values can be looked up using the index, quickly.

Comment: It'd be interesting to compare performance... `COUNT` should be pretty fast too. But +1 anyway.

Comment: @Nick The thing is, the optimizer probably won't figure out that it only needs to find two distinct items, so it will have to scan every record in the group.  Using only max and min, it just needs to check those two entries in the index.

Comment: You're definitely right about `MIN/MAX`. Probably I'm just over-optimistic about the optimiser with regards to `COUNT`.